# Python fuzzy match grouped by category

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to clean data using fuzzy match. 
The df like:

```
category description
1        almnd
1        almond
2        choc
2        choco
```

I want to have all similar descriptions to be same one under same category like that:

```
category description
1        almnd
1        almnd
2        choc
2        choc
```

Answer (score 2):

Fuzzy-wuzzy might be not up to such a task. You basically need to cluster words on similarity. Find few suggestion and code examples

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

If you find the amount of word and ideas excessive, for easy solution try Gensim `most_similar` function

[Python: clustering similar words based on word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425070/python-clustering-similar-words-based-on-word2vec)

Answer (score 1):

Convert your dataframe to a dictionary, and remap.

```
dico = dict(df.to_dict('split')['data'])
df['description'] = pd["category"].map(dico)
```

If your dataframe actually has more than these two columns check the accepted answer on dictionary extraction.

[dataframe to dict such that one column is the key and the other is the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941224/dataframe-to-dict-such-that-one-column-is-the-key-and-the-other-is-the-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)